# Two xml declaration in single xml file error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

My requirement is to create xml file and add xml elements to the existing xml file.

First I tried creating new xml file by following code.

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fStream, xmlSettings))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(true);
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Friends");
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Friend");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", "Safiq");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Like", "Char");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Unlike", "anger");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Nickname", "good");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Gift", "c#");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlWriter.Flush();
}
```

Next I tried adding new elements to the existing file.

```
XDocument XDOC = XDocument.Load(fStream);
XElement x = new XElement("Friend");
x.Add(new XElement("Name", "Safiq"));
x.Add(new XElement("Like", "Char"));
x.Add(new XElement("Unlike", "anger"));
x.Add(new XElement("Nickname", "good"));
x.Add(new XElement("Gift", "c#"));
XDOC.Descendants("Friends").Single().Add(x);
XDOC.Save(fStream);
```

But I am getting the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Friends>
    <Friend>
        <Name>Safiq</Name>
        <Like>Char</Like>
        <Unlike>anger</Unlike>
        <Nickname>good</Nickname>
        <Gift>c#</Gift>
    </Friend>
</Friends>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Friends>
    <Friend>
        <Name>Safiq</Name>
        <Like>Char</Like>
        <Unlike>anger</Unlike>
        <Nickname>good</Nickname>
        <Gift>c#</Gift>
    </Friend>
    <Friend>
        <Name>Safiq</Name>
        <Like>Char</Like>
        <Unlike>anger</Unlike>
        <Nickname>good</Nickname>
        <Gift>c#</Gift>
    </Friend>
</Friends>
```

Where am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the same stream to load and then save. After loading, the stream is positioned at the end of the file... so when you save the file afterwards, you're saving from that position.

I suggest you have a `using` statement to load the document and close the file, then another `using` statement to save the file:

```
XDocument doc;
using (var stream = ...)
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
// Manipulate doc
using (var stream = ...)
{
    doc.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: @Shafiq: Not if you're always adding data. But if you ever change your code to remove data instead, you'll end up with an invalid XML file due to the leftover data at the end. I'd use a fresh stream instead.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is position the stream to the beginning of its content

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fStream, xmlSettings))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(true);
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Friends");
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Friend");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", "Safiq");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Like", "Char");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Unlike", "anger");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Nickname", "good");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Gift", "c#");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlWriter.Flush();
}

// Reposition The stream
fStream.Position=0;

XDocument XDOC = XDocument.Load(fStream);
XElement x = new XElement("Friend");
x.Add(new XElement("Name", "Safiq"));
x.Add(new XElement("Like", "Char"));
x.Add(new XElement("Unlike", "anger"));
x.Add(new XElement("Nickname", "good"));
x.Add(new XElement("Gift", "c#"));
XDOC.Descendants("Friends").Single().Add(x);
XDOC.Save(fStream);
```